# Display XML on browser

Tags: c#, xml, string, web-services

I have developed a C# web service which returns XML via web browser.
I am getting value in C# string variable, this value is displayed in browser.
Let's say value I am getting is **display on broswer**. This value is stored in C# string variable as
String a = "display on browser";
In the browser it is displayed as (**first case**)

```
     <string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">display on browser</string>
```

But if I am splitting value of string variable as
String a = "display" + "\n" + "on" + "\n" + "browser";
I want value to be displayed in the broswer as (**second case**)

```
<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">Display  
on  
browser</string>.
```

But it does not display like this. It displays value in single line even after I added new lines into string variable.
I want output to be displayed as I mentioned in second case.
Please help me to achieve this.

Thanks in advance
Dastan Ali

Comment: Use `a.Replace("\n", "<br />");`

Comment: @Wiktor, I tried as you suggested but in the broswer it displays as <string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">display<br />on<br />browser</string>

Comment: Ok, no idea what browser you mean. Good luck. If you need more concrete help, please clarify the question by adding details, screens, examples, expected behavior.

Comment: As I can see someone down voted my question. I am sorry if the question is not clear. What I want to achieve is, I want to display XML on web browser. For this I am getting data from XML file. But there are two many restrictions to display XML data on browser therefore I am storing all the data of XML file into C# string variable. Problem in displaying string is that it displays data as I mentioned in first case. I want to display data on web browser as I mentioned in second case. Hope this makes my question clear